# SQL query error - Syntax error near 1 expecting %

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

Hi I am getting an error as syntax error near 1 expecting % @ line 16(Kauf.ID = %1). Please help :

```
select 

      SubWork_Title as "Workflow Title", 
      SubWorkTask_Title as "Step Name",
      KUAF.Name "User Account", 
      KUAF.LastName + ', ' + KUAF.FirstName "User Name", 
      Work_DateInitiated "Workflow Initiation Date", 
      SubWorkTask_PerformerID "User Id", 
      SubWork_WorkID "Workflow Id", 
      SubWork_SubWorkID "Subworkflow Id" 

from WSubWork, WSubWorkTask, WWork, KUAF 

where SubWork_SubWorkID = SubWorkTask_SubWorkID 
       and SubWorkTask_PerformerID = KUAF.ID 
       and SubWork_WorkID = Work_WorkID 
       and SubWorkTask_Status > 0 
       and KUAF.ID =%1 
       and Work_Status > 0
```

Comment: You've tagged `sql-server`, `oracle` and `plsql` here; theses are all completely different thing, I've removed all your conflicting tags.The error us quite clear here though (at least if you're using SQL Server): `KUAF.ID =%1` isn't a valid expression. Also, very importantly, why are you using `JOIN` syntax from the 1980's? [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins)

Comment: What this does mean 'and KUAF.ID =%1'  ? You should use  KUAF.ID ='%1' or if you want to use like then use KAUF.ID like '%1' .

Comment: What type does the Kuaf.ID column have? If it is a string you should use it like this: and `KUAF.ID = '%1'`. If it is a number (int, bigint, decimal) it cannot be equal to `%1`.

Comment: The error is pretty clear. What is `%1` supposed to mean? Did you try to write a parameterized query perhaps? What databased are you using? Each one has different syntax for parameters

Comment: I understand that but somehow its not clear to me - the error. I am not an SQL expert - can you please explain a bit? KUAF.ID = %1 - not sure why any error here

Comment: Yes I am writing a parameterized query - it is SQL server and this query was previously written in Oracle pl sql

Comment: in that case you need to use the sql server syntax to represent a variable e.g. @variablename. SQL syntax can be different in different DBMS engines

Comment: @RigertaDemiri I am getting an error when I put '%1' - Error converting data type varchar to bigint.

Comment: That means your column is a bigint. Try Kuaf.ID = 1. You are trying to compare a number (bigint) with a string (%1) when you should check a number with a number, or a string with a string (and so on, all data types).

Comment: What are you trying to do here? Does `KUAF.ID =%1 ` mean numbers that end with 1? So, for example, `65719841` and `987324651341` would evaluate to true, but `98467378` would be false?

Comment: No the value is not Kauf.ID = 1, its Kauf.ID = %1 where it is a parameter but I am not able to understand what correct sql syntax should be used here as this query was written previously in Oracle and it worked fine

Comment: @Larnu Yes that's correct

Comment: @user2152452 I already showed you the syntax in my comment earlier, did you not see it? Also you can easily look in the SQL Server documentation to find out the syntax...

Comment: @user2152452, what API, language, and driver are you using? With SQL Server ODBC, OLE DB and JDBC drivers, a `?` are used for parameter tokens in the query and those are mapped to supplied values by ordinal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're really trying to do here is:

```
AND RIGHT(KUAF.ID,1) = 1
```

This, however, is going to be a hit on the performance of your query, as it'll make the query non-SARGable. Thus, a better way would be to use a modulus:

```
AND KUAF.UD % 10 = 1
```

Example:

```
WITH VTE  AS (
    SELECT 654365465  AS  ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 869735476851  AS  ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 548947981  AS  ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 897684984  AS  ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 45679841  AS  ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 984768477  AS  ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 9876541  AS  ID
    UNION ALL
    SELECT 1  AS  ID
    )
SELECT ID
FROM VTE
WHERE ID % 10 = 1;
```

This returns:

```
ID
---------------------------------------
869735476851
548947981
45679841
9876541
1
```

Answer (score 1):

With SQL Server ODBC, OLE DB and JDBC drivers, `?` is used for parameter markers within the query and those are mapped to supplied values by ordinal. The `%1` here is interpreted as a T-SQL bitwise AND with literal 1, not a parameter. With the SqlClient API, parameter names are used as parameter markers within queries (e.g. `@YourParameter`) and passed by name from the app code.

If you need help with properly passing parameters, post the client code and specify the language and driver are you using.